# Design for following situation having gtest procedure

Tags: c++, design-patterns, googletest

In my current implementation i have 2 files (i am stuck and not getting any further)

```
//firstFile.cpp
class first
{
    //some object of xyz class
};

first f;  //global

TEST(Suite, Testcase
{
//do something
}



//secondFile.cpp
class second
{
public:
//some data members

void function()
}
```

Task :- I want to call TEST (consider it a special function, when it is called, object of first (i.e. global object defined will be created). In test i want to save some data for latter processing, which obviously i can't do in first class as it will be initialized on every TEST call.

Problem :- I though of having a separate class (in another .cpp file) which have required data structure to be saved. I want a way to access those data structure in TEST procedure and keep on adding the data over previous data with every TEST call. I can't have an object for second class in firstFile.cpp as it will also be created/destroyed on every call.

Any suggestion? Also i can't do anything about TEST procdedure, this is the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

In gtest you can define test fixtures. It's a bit like defining a context for a set of tests. It gives you means to SetUp/TearDown stuff before/after each of your tests, but also before/after your test suite runs. Note that `SetUp` and `TearDown` are case sensitive.

```
struct MyFixture : testing::Test
{
private:
    // stuff
protected:
    //! Called before running all tests
    static void SetUpTestCase();
    //! Called after running all tests
    static void TearDownTestCase();

    //! Called before each test
    void SetUp() {}
    //! Called after each test
    void TearDown() {}

public:
    static SomeSharedObject& GetSharedObjInTest() {}
};
```

and in the test case you would need to call

```
TEST_F(MyFixture, MyTest_Name)
{
// some cool stuff here
}
```

You could simply create a static instance of `first` inside that fixture, initialize it inside SetUp() and use a static getter to access it from inside your different tests.

refer to the documentation [gtest - Sharing resources between tests in the same test case](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/V1_6_AdvancedGuide.md)

Comment: If you have already developed a lot of support routines to be used with `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` methods, won't the above solution require making them also static in order to utilize those functions? In effect this is not a practical solution IMO. I still cannot fathom why GTest include the `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` methods which mirror the functionality of Constructor and Destructor. In an elegant world the Constructor and Destructor could have served the purpose of static void setUpTestCase() and static void TearDownTestCase() by initializing all resources common to all test cases.